# Access request params through extended/super class NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, knex.js

I am new to nodejs project/backend with type script.

I have requirement in which i have to access request params through extended/super class for all api methods.

Code should be similar to below

```
Write base class called API. All Controllers should be extended from that base class.
Code example: user.controller.ts

export class UserController extends API {
      ……….
      ……….
      @Get('route_name')
      async getUser(){
            //code to get user
            //this.body - this is object of base API class. It should give us access to regular request.body. Same goes for this.query - request.query, this.params - request.params. 
                         //In other words this is wrapper for request.body (query, params)
       }
      ……….
      ……….
}
```

I am not sure if it's possible or not.

If it is then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

That's totally possible, I have two options for you to achieve that

1. [`ts-express-decoratores`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-express-decorators) which is a plugin that provides functions to achieve that approach on top of Express

Here's an Example:

```
import {Controller, Get} from "@tsed/common";
import * as Express from "express";

export interface Calendar{
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

@Controller("/calendars")
export class CalendarCtrl {

    @Get("/:id")
    async get(request: Express.Request, response: Express.Response): Promise<Calendar> {
        return {id: request.params.id, name: "test"};
    }
}
```

2. [`NestJS`](https://docs.nestjs.com) which is a Framework that has provides this out of the box

Example:

```
import { Controller, Get, Post } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
    @Post()
    create() {
        return 'This action adds a new cat';
    }

    @Get()
    findAll() {
        return 'This action returns all cats';
    }
}
```

Comment: From your example i am not understanding how can i create API class that can be extend in other class & access request params through API class like i mentioned requirement in question.